# converting promise chain to async/await

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

```
function testFunc(name) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Hello there ' + name + '!'), 3000)
      })
}

console.log("Calling testFunc !!!!")
testFunc('Sam').then(data => console.log(data))
console.log("Done !!!!")
```

The code above logs *Calling testFunc !!!!* then *Done !!!!* then *Hello there Sam!*

How can I use async/await in this situation to log *Calling testFunc !!!!* then *Hello there Sam!* then *Done !!!!*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 'textFunc' is asynchronous, meaning it takes a couple seconds to complete, `console.log('done')` will get executed before `.then(...)`. So you can just add `console.log('done')` into the `.then(...)` part, or use something like the code below.

```
console.log("Calling testFunc !!!!")
let data = await testFunc('Sam')
console.log(data)
console.log("Done !!!!")
```

you might also have to wrap everything in an async function

```
async someFunction() {
    console.log("Calling testFunc !!!!")
    let data = await testFunc('Sam')
    console.log(data)
    console.log("Done !!!!")
}

someFunction()
```

Comment: wow that's awesome. solved my problem! Thank you!